Route pulseaudio to more than 2 devices
I have a gstreamer pipeline that tee's audio into multiple sinks (devices). I've a bunch of sinks I want to route the audio to but it doesn't seem to work. When I tee the pipeline to max 2 devices, there is audio through the devices. It can be any 2 of the many sinks I've set up, the audio works. But when I try to tee it to a 3rd device, there's no audio anywhere. I've confirmed that all the devices (sinks) work on their own or with just another sink. But not when it is more than 2.
What's blocking the audio from getting routed to other devices sinks? I'm running pulseaudio in system mode and have not made any changes to the system.pa file.
